# fastest way to concatenate large numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I am doing some optical flow analysis. The goal is to iterate through every frame in a long movie, calculate the dense optical flow, and append the resulting angles and magnitudes to a growing numpy array. I found that it takes longer and longer to complete every consecutive loop, and I'm not sure why. Here is a simple example loop that recapitulates the problem:

```
import numpy as np

arraySize = (1, 256, 256)          # correct array size
emptyArray = np.zeros(arraySize)   # empty array to fill with angles from every image pair
timeElapsed = []                   # empty list to fill with time values

for i in range(100):               # iterates through the frames in the image stack
    start = time.time()            # start the time
    newArray = np.zeros(arraySize) # makes an example new array
    emptyArray = np.concatenate((emptyArray, newArray)) # concats new and growing arrays
    end = time.time()              # stop the time
    timeElapsed.append(end-start)  # append the total time for the loop to the growing list
```

If I then plot the time elapsed for each loop I get a linear increase for every trip through the loop. In this example it's still tolerable, but with my actual dataset it isn't.

[image]

I am guessing that the larger arrays take more time to work with, but I'm not sure what to do to avoid that. Is there a better, faster, or more Pythonic way to do this?

------------- edit -------------

Per mathfux's suggestion: I modified the loop as follows:

```
arraySize = (1, 256, 256)          # correct array size
emptyArray = np.concatenate([np.zeros(arraySize) for i in range(100)])   # empty array to fill with angles from every image pair
timeElapsed = []                   # empty list to fill with time values

for i in range(100):               # iterates through the frames in the image stack
    start = time.time()            # start the time
    newArray = np.zeros(arraySize) # makes an example new array
    emptyArray[i] = newArray[0]    # overwrites empty array with newarray values at the relevant position
    end = time.time()              # stop the time
    timeElapsed.append(end-start)  # append the total time for the loop to the growing list
```

Now the time/loop is pretty consistent between iterations:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If your data contains zeros only, `np.zeros((100, 256, 256), dtype=int)` should be sufficient. The most efficient way is to flatten your data and then reshape it.

Comment: Would specifying the dtype make this more memory efficient? If I understand correctly, I can't specify "int" because I will be replacing these values with floats.

Comment: IMO it would be better to modify mathfux's answer with this update, rather than adding it to the question.

Comment: I didn't know that I could modify mathfux's answer with this update, when I click "edit" it says that the suggested edit queue is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you append a new array, new memory is being allocated to create a bigger one and record data into it. This is very expensive. A better solution is to allocate a specific size of memory once and then record your date using `np.concatenate` only once:

```
np.concatenate([np.zeros(arraySize) for i in range(100)])
```

Answer (score 1):

This way seems to be 28 times faster in my Pc

```
start = time.time()                    # start the time
arrays = []
for i in range(100):                   # iterates through the frames in the image stack
    arrays.append(np.zeros(arraySize)) 

#Concatenate all in one time     
newArray=np.concatenate(arrays)
end = time.time()              # stop the time
timeElapsed2 = end-start  

print("Elapesed:",timeElapsed2)

print("sum elapsed times of first method:", np.sum(timeElapsed))
```

Elapsed : 0.021436214447021484

Sum elapsed times of first method: 0.6163454055786133

Comment: Awesome! I ran this and mathfux's answer 10,000 times and they were essentially identical; mathfux = 13.58ms, yours = 13.63ms

Answer (score 1):

Using accelerators could increase the code speed by using GPU or TPU capabilities e.g. by using **jax** library your code will run perhaps [about 1000 times faster than other answers](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15jBe9IooInQqZhxfTAK1zSOxVeKTyLMZ?usp=sharing) (about 40 to 50 **µs** per loop) using google colab TPU:

```
from jax import jit

@jit
def zac():
    arraySize = (1, 256, 256)          # correct array size
    emptyArray = np.zeros(arraySize)   # empty array to fill with angles from every image pair
    timeElapsed = []                   # empty list to fill with time values

    for i in range(100):               # iterates through the frames in the image stack
        start = time.time()            # start the time
        newArray = np.zeros(arraySize) # makes an example new array
        emptyArray = np.concatenate((emptyArray, newArray)) # concats new and growing arrays
        end = time.time()              # stop the time
        timeElapsed.append(end-start)  # append the total time for the loop to the growing list
```

The result, calculated by `%timeit -n10000 zac()`, will be as follows:

```
10000 loops, best of 5: 47.7 µs per loop
```